# read.csv parameter stringsAsFactors not working?

Tags: r, csv, r-factor, file-import

Based on the documentation `read.csv`, the parameter `stringsAsFactors`, when set, should cause quoted data values to be interpreted as factors. Consider the following data file, which we will call `test.csv`.

```
"a",b,c 
"1",2,3 
"3",2,3
```

When I try to read this data using `read.csv`, it does not appear to parse the first column as a factor.

```
foo = read.csv("test.csv", stringsAsFactor=T)
is.factor(foo$a)
```

Output:

```
[1] FALSE
```

I tried to use the column name without quotes, but that did not work either.
How can I correct this?

Comment: `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`? Does missing an "s" matter?

Comment: As far as I know, `T==TRUE`. Also, where am I missing an `s`?

Comment: in the argument name of `stringsAsFactors`, not `stringsAsFactor`

Comment: @alittleboy, surprisingly, that `s` makes no  difference at all.

Comment: Read about argument matching for why that doesn't matter: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the default behaviour for read.csv (which is a wrapper for read.table) is to try to coerce characters to numerics.  See `? type.covert` which is called by read.csv as it tries to assign an appropriate type to your columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example data are coercible to numeric. Try with data that are not so coercible:

```
foo <- read.csv(text='"a",b,c 
"1",2,3 
"3",2,3 
"a",2,3 ', stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
> foo$a
# [1] 1 3 a
# Levels: 1 3 a
```

Otherwise use `colClasses`:

```
foo <- read.csv(text='"a",b,c 
"1",2,3 
"3",2,3 ', colClasses=c('factor','numeric','numeric'))
> foo$a
# [1] 1 3
# Levels: 1 3
```

Or you could convert using `as.factor` after reading the data in.

Comment: Can I force data that is coercible to numeric to be treated as factors?

Comment: @merlin2011: Yes, by overriding the individual column types with the `columnClasses` argument, as Thomas shows.